# How can I add a type from an npm package into a `d.ts` file declared namespace?

Tags: typescript, import, namespaces, .d.ts

I have this `TYPES.d.ts` file where I declare a `TYPES` namespace

```
declare namespace TYPES {

  type TYPE_A = XXX;
  type TYPE_B = YYY;

}
```

And then I use is like: `const someFunc = (param: TYPES.TYPE_A): void => { ... };`

It works fine.

But now I'd like to add a type on the `TYPES` namespace that is a return type from a type that exists on an NPM package.

**TYPES.d.ts**

```
import type { SomeType } from "some-npm-package";

declare namespace TYPES {
  type SOME_TYPE = ReturnType<typeof SomeType>;
}
```

But this "breaks" the `d.ts` file, because it seems Typescript considers it to be a module, instead of a definition file.

How can I achieve that and still be able to access it through my namespace?

Comment: it works in ts playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCAqAmgAoCiAyvAN4BQ188ALgJ6b7EkD6AgvALzwByKAIDcdRizakOAIT6CARqNoBfWqEiwEyNFhxTyVcc1bwyAeQCynQqXkCwytdTAB7ROgbx0rtADEAV0QweQAKbBhUAC54W3IAOgtrDjiASj4APip4cWoVESA

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks. But the problem is with the `import` statement. In your example, there's just the declared namespace, which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a way of doing it:

**TYPES.d.ts**

```
declare namespace TYPES {
  type SOME_TYPE = ReturnType<typeof import("some-npm-package").SomeType>;
  type OTHER_TYPE = typeof import("some-npm-package").SomeType
  type FOO_TYPE = typeof import("./someFile").FooType  // ALSO WORKS WITH SRC FILES
}
```

This way you avoid the top-level import that "breaks" the `d.ts` file declared namespace.